# Alternative solution to Kubernete ingress rules for 404 resource error

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, ingress

For two days I was plagued by the following scenario:
We have a kubernetes cluster (Rancher GUI) where within a namespace I will host a few different services. I wanted to set up an ingress controller to route traffic based on incoming path.
When trying a simple POC setup, using the following ingress, the index.html would load, but none of the resources.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: >-
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: poc-web
                port:
                  number: 9080
            path: /test(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
```

However, that would result in a 404, as the index.html paths were given as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

While some online resources claim the relative paths should work fine with this ingress, it did not, as the request would go to domain.com/style.css due to the rewrite, instead of domain.com/test/style.css.

The only way I could make it work for me, is to prefix the final path to the index href:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test/style.css">
```

While it works like a charm, it also means it cannot be tested like this locally, as this path does not exist.

Is there a better way to handle this?
I assume one way is to use more complicated regex in the rewrite, but yikes.
I feel like there is a more elegant solution, one that works locally and via the ingress - but I cannot put my finger on it.

---

Note that index.html is served via a very simple nginx with the following config:

```
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid /tmp/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_temp;
    proxy_temp_path       /tmp/proxy_temp_path;
    fastcgi_temp_path     /tmp/fastcgi_temp;
    uwsgi_temp_path       /tmp/uwsgi_temp;
    scgi_temp_path        /tmp/scgi_temp;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen 9080;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        server_name    localhost;
    }

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```